# I get an exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException while I am executing a JDBC program

Tags: java, jdbc

Here is my code

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class  AccountDeletionApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException 
    {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the Acc no:");
    int ano=s.nextInt();
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","scott","tiger");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    int n=st.executeUpdate("delete from ACCOUNT1 where ACCNO="+ano);
    if(n==1)
        System.out.println("account deleted succesfully");
    else
        System.out.println("account doesnt exist");
    st.close();
    con.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a bad practice to use string concatenation in query. this can cause sql injection...you should you preparedstatement..google it..there are plenty of examples :)

Comment: Please add the exception + stacktrace to your question

Answer (score 0):

Please post the entire stack trace, but most likely your driver is not on the class-path.  It doesn't ship with JVM.  Go [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) to download it, and add it to your classpath.